# Can I do a match search across two columns to get a 0/1 matrix output

Tags: if-statement, matrix, networking, match

I am attempting to do a network analysis, and for this I need an affiliation matrix
The output I'm looking for is to have all projects listed across, and then value 1 if a name has a connection to the project (i.e. Name a has been on P1), and 0 if not, for all names.

My data set consists of two columns; column B are all projects, and Column C is names connected to the project in column B

As such:

```
| Project | Name |
|---------|------|
|Project 1 | Name a|
|Project 1 | Name b|
|Project 1 | Name c|
|Project 2 | Name d|
|Project 2 | Name e|
|Project 2 | Name f|
|Project 2 | Name g|
|Project 3 | Name a|
|Project 3 | Name b|
```

[Picture of data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNjXI.png)

The desired output of the above example would be:

```
| name| P1 | P2 | P3 |
|-----|----|----|----|
|Name a| 1  |  0 | 1 | 
|Name b| 1  |  0 | 1 |
|Name c| 1  |  0 | 0 |
|Name d| 0  |  1 | 0 |
|Name e| 0  |  1 | 0 |
|Name f| 0  |  1 | 0 |
|Name g| 0  |  1 | 0 |
```

[picture of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGWz2.png)

How do I based on the data columns I have, ask excel to input a 1, if both the name and project matches in the data columns, and 0 if there is no match between name and project?

I hope my question makes sense.

I've tried something with match functions, that didn't turn out well, and most successful has been: `=IF((IF($G$1=B10;1;0)+IF(E10=C10;1;0)-1)>0;1;0)`

However, 1) my data set has 1500 names, and 3000+ projects so I'm not sure how to do the above effectively; and 2) the formular dosen't work when the list of names in the matrix do not match up with the exact cell of names in the column data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem: =IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A;AB$1;$B:$B;$D2)>0;1;0)
Where column A is projects, B are the names.